# No line breaks in each reference in bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I am a begginer of latex. I am using bibtex as follows.

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{References}

Now there are line breaks and I would like to remove them.
How can I do this?

**Currently**
[1] Authors.

Paper title.

Journal.

**Should be**
[1] Authors, Paper title, Journal...

Thank you!

```
    \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
 \bibsection\parindent \z@\bibpreamble\bibfont\list
   {\@biblabel{\arabic{NAT@ctr}}}{\@bibsetup{#1}%
    \setcounter{NAT@ctr}{0}}%
    \ifNAT@openbib
      \renewcommand\newblock{\par}
    \else
      \renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}%
    \fi
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
    \let\citeN\cite \let\shortcite\cite
    \let\citeasnoun\cite
 }{\def\@noitemerr{%
  \PackageWarning{natbib}
     {Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist\vskip-\lastskip}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without an example document that reproduces the behaviour. Some classes have an option called `openbib` that may introduce additional line breaks in the bibliography. Check if you use that option at some point.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! I added a part of code of natbib.sty. Do you think this Is related to the problem?

Comment: The code you have shown is not the original code in `natbib.sty`. But this code alone is not the cause of your issue. You need to show us a compilable example document that reproduces the problem with as little irrelevant code as possible (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).